# Where can I buy Windows Server 2012 Essentials?

Tags: windows-server-2012

It's been out for a week or so now (give or take) but I can't find anything about how to actually purchase it. Do I need to download the trial and then upgrade it or something? Is there any where that actually sells it?

Comment: It's available almost anywhere that sells Windows Server software, both online and brick/mortar.

Comment: I haven't seen it any where and Alen's answer explains why.

Comment: I don't see how this is off topic, I read the FAQ before asking this question and I think needing to know where to buy server software is just as important as asking for help on how to install ect. It is answerable (as you can see I have gotten a definitive answer) And it did not promote a discussion like "what shop is better?"

Comment: Ah, I see what happened.  I had seen a "purchase" card for it on the shelf at my local computer store.  Went back yesterday and noticed that the card said it was for Pre-Orders.  Hadn't noticed that the first time and assumed it was out.  As for the off-topic, I would consider this would fall into the category of off-topic and too localized.  The reason is that both shopping recommendations and questions whose answers will not be useful to "future visitors" are considered off topic for this site.

Comment: @BBlake thanks, I understand. I guess I'm lucky I got an answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essentials version is still in RC (Release Candidate) state, it should be finalized and put in RTM (Release To Manufacturer) by the end of 2012.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2012/08/21/windows-server-2012-release-candidate-essentials-available-now.aspx

If you go to the official windows server essentials page, you can only download the release candidate. That is why there is no option to buy it.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/windows-server-essentials/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Please view this [PDF](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/4/B/04BD0EB1-42FE-488B-919F-3981EF9B2101/WS2012_Licensing-Pricing_Datasheet.pdf). The relevant data is the picture below.

**EDIT** As pointed out by sshow, the prices have changed since the picture went live. I'm not going to keep taking screen shots and updating them, please click on the link though to see the latest prices.

[image]

[Source](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/windows-server-essentials/default.aspx)

Comment: Thanks but I've seen that before, I wanted to know where I can buy it.

Comment: The PDF I looked at today said the price was $501